# PartialRecursive<T> doesn't work for generics

Tags: typescript

I am building a type that should work like `Partial<T>`. But recursively and it should also cover arrays.

I have created this a type definition for `PartialRecursive<T>` that works perfectly with any predefined types I can think of. Including arrays. It looks like this:

```
type PartialRecursive<T> = T extends object
    ? PartialRecursiveObject<T>
    : T extends (infer U)[]
    ? PartialRecursiveArray<U>
    : T;

type PartialRecursiveObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: PartialRecursive<T[P]>;
};

interface PartialRecursiveArray<U> extends Array<PartialRecursive<U>> { }
```

I would expect this definition to work with generics also. But somehow it fails when it is used with generics. For example this:

```
const mergeDeep = <TLeft, TRight>(
    left: TLeft,
    right: TRight,
) => {
    let myVar: PartialRecursive<TLeft & TRight> = left;
};
```

throws compilation error. `error Type 'TLeft' is not assignable to type 'PartialRecursive<TLeft & TRight>'`
But the same thing with predefined types work absolutely correct. For example this:

```
type TLeft = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

type TRight = [{
    c: number;
}]

let myVar: TLeft = {
    a: 'asdasd',
    b: 2
};

let partial: PartialRecursive<TLeft & TRight> = myVar;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwEoQMYFcEDOyAbhADwAqAfFALxQVQQAewEAdgCYFQD2ARgCscwALAAoKFKgB+WIhToseQiQgB5ISMpUJ0qAC4GTVh25QAFMnYAzCAigBVAJQBtALp7pc+ElSYcfCJSAEEEBDgQMkddSWkjCgBuCQlQSHk-JUDVUk1hbGAdOigAby8pVxgoaygAawgQXhsGdxkjX0UAlWDyCkr3KmTxAF8hiWs2BBs4bGgO-2UgtTCIqJiTNi4eFciyeazutWiqGhKoYZTxVPA5hQXsnoB1XgRax+RgAAsAcQ57ZGwBCK9DO5SglWq7DqDSaLTaDH6GzMPAE+WAUDBPjuByWpGer3eX1+7H+gMo-RoYISiJYm3MVls9icbncGLiUixmS6uIg+LeHx+fwQAKBfRgAw8bP01PFiTZo0u2F47AI6IAtvYAOYQAAiEAgYGKlAAMhAbMAADQMDDITWfYBUCxgtBm4AJU3mi1g4V2t3W232r3iZx0U7OiDogDuL1qBHa2O5OV5McJgpJwrJFA96IAZP7fTR6C7zUN9C70exeMA+XGMp1FkmTa6oHmKDaC8Vi8AhgqruIgA)

Comment: This is one of those casses where you just need to use a type assertion. The compiler can't follow those conditional types while they still contain unresolved type parameters so it just errs on the assignment since it can't prove it safe.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it makes sense. But can you explain why for example this definition that doesn't cover arrays but uses conditional types work with generics.
`type PartialRecursive<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends object 
    ? PartialRecursive<T[P]> 
    : T[P] extends (infer U)[] 
    ? PartialRecursive<T[P]>[] 
    : T[P];
};`

Comment: I have added a playground link about what I mean in my question as comments do not allow large links.